# Questions about nftables and rule processing order

Tags: linux, debian, nftables

My understanding from reading is that once a rule matches, no further rules are evaluated. However; my experience with the following example seems to indicate otherwise. Looking for some clarity on this.

```
table netdev retag {
    chain tagin {
            type filter hook ingress devices = $lan priority -149; policy accept;
            
            ip saddr 10.0.0.0/8 ip daddr 10.0.0.0/8 ip dscp set af21 counter;
            
            ip saddr 10.0.1.0/24 ip daddr 10.0.2.0/24 ip dscp set af31 counter;
    }
}
```

If the above statement was true then "nft list ruleset" should show hits against the  first rule and 0 hits against the second rule since the first rule would always match before the second rule. However; see hits against both. Am I missing something silly here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some actions, such as `accept, drop, reject` prevent further rule processing.

Other actions, such as `counter, log` perform their task and continue to the next rule.

In this slightly modified example I added `accept` to the first rule, this will prevent further evaluation.

```
table netdev retag {
    chain tagin {
            type filter hook ingress devices = $lan priority -149; policy accept;
            
            ip saddr 10.0.0.0/8 ip daddr 10.0.0.0/8 ip dscp set af21 counter accept;
            
            ip saddr 10.0.1.0/24 ip daddr 10.0.2.0/24 ip dscp set af31 counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the answer I was looking for.